# How to order a SELECT statement by the number of matching foreign keys?

Tags: sql, django

Imagine a "house" table in a database has 7 foreign keys:

- Location
- Price
- Population
- Size
- Schools
- Shops
- Transport

(Some of the relationships are in fact many to many relationships).

I want to show a list of houses, sorted in descending order by the number of matching foreign keys.

The best result would be where all 7 foreign keys have values, including a large number of values in the many to many relationships.

The next best result would be where all 7 foreign keys have values, but have fewer values in the many to many relationships.

The next best result would be where 6 of the foreign keys have a value.

The next best result would be where 5 of the foreign keys have a value.

And so on until only 1 of the foreign keys has a value.

Is there a way to do this type of sorting in SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried using horrible nested "case when something then 0 else 1 end"...

Comment: Can you atleast share dummy data in tabular form & your tried query, a fiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

It will be not very simple because you must check all the foreign keys, so you must tell all this 7 conditions.
You can put in order by eg.:

```
select
    ...
from
    thistable
order by
    case when exists (select 1 from table1 where id=thistable.fk1) then 1 else 0 end + 
    case when exists (select 1 from table2 where id=thistable.fk2) then 1 else 0 end + 
    ...
    desc
```

So the more foreign key have connected record(s) the higher the value will be.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the foreign keys have a value is not too tricky. Try something like this:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY Case When fk1 Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End +
    Case When fk2 Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 +
    ... DESC ,
    (Select Count(*) From ManyToManyTable1 Where MyTableID = MyTable.ID) +
    (Select Count(*) From ManyToManyTable2 Where MyTableID = MyTable.ID) DESC
```